# call a function inside a public function in php

Tags: php

I am trying to call a function with variables passed, but it's not working.

```
public function Delete_Update($uid, $msg_id) 
{
    $sql = mysql_query("select uploads_grab from messages where msg_id='$msg_id' and uid_fk='$uid'");
    $roww = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
    $uploads_grab_id=$roww['uploads_grab'];
    if ($uploads_grab_id != '0') {
        $sq = mysql_query("delete from user_uploads_grab where id='$uploads_grab_id'");
    }

    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `comments` WHERE msg_id_fk = '$msg_id' and cfid='$uid' ") or die(mysql_error());
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `messages` WHERE msg_id = '$msg_id' and uid_fk='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());

    after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');
    return true;           
}
```

In the above code I am calling a function `after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');` but it's not working

the after_del function is

```
class delme
   {
      function after_del($uid,$delid,$type)
      {

        $sql=mysql_query("select created from messages where msg_id='$delid' and uid_fk='$uid'");
        $roww=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $created=$roww['created'];
        $del_noti = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `notification` WHERE time_stamp = '$created' and owner_user_id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());
        $del_activity = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `activity` WHERE time_stamp = '$created' and owner_user_id='$uid'") or die(mysql_error());         


      }

      }
$del_result=new delme();
```

Comment: "It is not working" is so detailed.

Comment: What is the function definition of 'after_del'? What error message are you getting?

Comment: Is `after_del` a method of the same class? If it is, you need to call it as `$this->after_del`

Comment: Has mysql encountered an error?

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: no the after_del is not the method of the same class.

Comment: Where is `after_del` declared?

Comment: in a different file where i included it in the file where Delete_Update is declared

Comment: You still need to tell us, just what is 'not working'. What is it supposed to do, and what does it do instead? Are you getting any error message?

Comment: the thing is i am not getting a error message also . and it is suppose to delete the notification and activity related to the update ,if i delete the update .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is after_del in the same class as Delete_Update? If it is then you can access like this:

```
$this->after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');
```

Or if after_del is in the same class but is a static method then access like this:

```
self::after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');
```

If after_del is defined in another class as a public method, then first create an object of that class and call the object's method:

```
$otherClass = new OtherClass();
$otherClass->after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');
```

Or if after_del is defined as a static public method of another class then call it like this:

```
OtherClass::after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');
```

Comment: not working , i am updating the otherClass and can you please suggest me according to that

Comment: make sure the file that has the class that after_del is in is included

Comment: yes its included friend. i checked every possible things before posing for help. :)

Comment: i forgot to include brackets in $otherClass = new OtherClass(); , just edited

Comment: its k i noticed that friend , already used the correct way still not working

Comment: inside your Delete_Update function you should have:
$delme = new delme();
$delme->after_del($uid,$msg_id,'wall_post');

Comment: thank you , i found that after_del was being called after update being deleted and i was to fetch timestamp from update , since there was no timestamp the notifications were not getting deleted. now its working just fine . thanks for the help

Comment: if u are certain that is all correct and u are not getting error msgs and you are not getting what you expect then you should be more specific about what you expect to happen and more specific about what is not happening as expected in your question